# Pandas replacing the one column value with other

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, python-3.5

Here is the sample data:

```
Time,RangeGreen,RangeRed,DistanceGreenRed,SlopeGreen,SlopeRed,PreviousCandleColor,CurrentCandleColor
2018.04.02 00:01:01,30-40,20-30,14.42241040084485,0.002837507264410963,-0.002233901393132696,Green,indecisive
2018.04.02 00:03:06,40-50,30-40,9.228956001044772,3.969502900848433,7.203315124348411,Green,indecisive
2018.04.02 00:04:06,10-20,30-40,-13.69498672180752,-19.36590965829607,-2.850639197642629,Red,indecisive
```

I am willing to replace the `CurrentCandleColor` values with the `PreviousCandleColor` but the 0th value of `CurrentCandleColor` should be the 1st value of `PreviousCandleColor`.

Hence my final value must be:

```
Time,RangeGreen,RangeRed,DistanceGreenRed,SlopeGreen,SlopeRed,PreviousCandleColor,CurrentCandleColor
2018.04.02 00:01:01,30-40,20-30,14.42241040084485,0.002837507264410963,-0.002233901393132696,Green,Green
2018.04.02 00:03:06,40-50,30-40,9.228956001044772,3.969502900848433,7.203315124348411,Green,Red
2018.04.02 00:04:06,10-20,30-40,-13.69498672180752,-19.36590965829607,-2.850639197642629,Red,indecisive
```

I tried to move it somewhat like this;

```
df['CurrentCandleColor'] = df[1:'PreviousCandleColor']
```

But I got the following error:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.range.RangeIndex'> with these indexers [PreviousCandleColor] of <class 'str'>
```

Kindly, help me.

Comment: Its called shifting

Comment: `df['CurrentCandleColor'] = df['PreviousCandleColor'].shift()`

Comment: @Dark - agree with you.

Comment: But it didn't work for me. Had you tried. Please let me know.

Comment: @JafferWilson - Can you explain more?

Comment: Check the output I received after running the command and what I expected: https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/53f46959bf58d4fe41b7f4237ee6fe72

Comment: Please check the outputs that I was expecting please let me know if anything ambiguous

Comment: Hence, my question is not what Dark had marked me as duplicate.

Comment: @JafferWilson - Can you check edited answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) if no `NaNs` here:

```
a = df.loc[df.index[-1], 'CurrentCandleColor']
df['CurrentCandleColor'] = df['PreviousCandleColor'].shift(-1).fillna(a)
print (df)
                  Time        ...         CurrentCandleColor
0  2018.04.02 00:01:01        ...                      Green
1  2018.04.02 00:03:06        ...                        Red
2  2018.04.02 00:04:06        ...                 indecisive

[3 rows x 8 columns]
```

Or:

```
df['CurrentCandleColor'] =df['PreviousCandleColor'].shift(-1).fillna(df['CurrentCandleColor'])
```

If possible `NaN`s values first get last value of column and then set back:

```
last = df['CurrentCandleColor'].values[-1]
df['CurrentCandleColor'] = df['PreviousCandleColor'].shift(-1)
df.loc[df.index[-1], 'CurrentCandleColor'] = last
```

Comment: perhaps commenting would be better. There are so many answers for shift na ?

Comment: Great that help . Thank you very much.